# discord js permissions to execute command positions

Tags: discord, discord.js

```
      if (
    !message.member.roles.cache.some(
      (role) =>
        role.id === doc1.lady.cargo1 ||
        role.id === doc1.lady.cargo2 ||
        role.id === doc1.lady.cargo3 ||
        role.id === doc1.lady.cargo4 ||
        role.id === doc1.lady.cargo5 ||
        role.id === doc1.lady.cargo6
    )
  )
    return message.reply(
      `${message.author}, você não tem permissão para executar esse comando`
    );
```

db = cargo1 : "951689717139791922"

even though I have one of the positions mentioned, it turns out that I am without permission

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, it should work.

```js
const filter = [doc1.lady.cargo1, doc1.lady.cargo2, doc1.lady.cargo3, doc1.lady.cargo4, doc1.lady.cargo5, doc1.lady.cargo6];

if (message.member.roles.cache.filter(r => !filter.includes(r.id)).size == 0)
    return message.reply(
      `${message.author}, você não tem permissão para executar esse comando`
    );
```

Also instead of define each time the value with +1

You can make this

```js
const filter = ['id1', 'id2', 'id3'];
if (message.member.roles.cache.filter(r => !filter.includes(r.id)).size == 0)
    return message.reply(
      `${message.author}, você não tem permissão para executar esse comando`
    );
```

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id')

Comment: Do you have GuildMember intents enabled ?

Comment: I edited and tested the code, it work, you need to have guild members intents if its not done already

Comment: @Lemaaa last I checked, you don't need that intent to check roles

Comment: But you need it to access the GuildMember object @MrMythical

Comment: @Lemaaa no, you don't

Answer (score 0):

Use `Collection#hasAny()`

```js
if (!message.member.roles.cache.hasAny(...Object.values(doc1.lady))) return message.reply(`...`)
```

`.hasAny()` takes any rest parameter, like `.hasAny(roleId1, roleId2, roleId3)` or even `.hasAny(...arrayOfRoleIds)`